# Can someone explain the effects visible in Google Image Swirl?

Tags: jquery

How are the expanding and shrinking effects done?

http://image-swirl.googlelabs.com/html?q=volcano#388

Is it possible with jQuery UI animate stuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google uses flash for this.  Something similar *might* be possible in jquery, but it's going to be more complicated and will probably not be practical to run on basic machines.